# error when starting windows 10 virtual machine

Tags: windows

when i boot up the windows 10 machine it gives me an error and the error is VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Certain guests (e.g. OS/2 and QNX) require this feature and will fail to boot without it.

please someone help me!

Comment: Look at: https://superuser.com/questions/597121/vt-x-amd-v-hardware-acceleration-is-not-available-on-your-system

Comment: You need to activate VT-x for Intel CPUs or AMD-V for AMD CPUs in your BIOS/UEFI, if such options are available. If not your computer has no virtualization support as required for a Windows 64-bit VM or others.

Comment: First, this is an Ubuntu forum not Windows forum.
That could be because BIOS haven't been configurated as VT-x acceleration needs.
To this go to BIOS and enable the Virtualization technology.
If this solution not resolve your incidence go to the configuration menu of Virtualbox and enable the Enable VT-x/AMD-V checkbox (Configuration/System/Acceleration)
If this solution not resolve your incidence try to update your BIOS.